# ifc.js - Unexpected style type message when loading model

Tags: javascript, three.js, ifc

Loading IFC files with the ifc.js library i often get many messages like this in console:

```
Unexpected style type: 3800577675 at 213152 (web-ifc-api.js: 933)
Unexpected style type: 3800577675 at 213511 (web-ifc-api.js: 933)
...
```

What are they due to?
Is it possible to prevent them from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

It means that there's something that hasn't been implemented in web-ifc yet. You can create an issue in web-ifc to request for the implementation.

[Response from Ansoni in IFC.js Discord](https://discord.com/channels/799990228336115742/800000126998675457/880588583440908288)

Comment: issue created: https://github.com/IFCjs/web-ifc/issues/211